# Where do I find charms for Wyrm elementals?

Tags: monsters, world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, werewolf-the-apocalypse-1st-edition

The wyrm elementals in *[Book of the Wyrm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Wyrm)* for Werewolf: The Apocalypse have charms that I can't find descriptions for.

For example, the  Toxin elemental (pg. 100) has the charms Visceral Agony and Body Wrack. I don't see these referenced in *Book of the Wyrm*, nor in several other books that I checked.

There are Garou gifts by those names, but I'm unsure why a charm would reference an existing power like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is in fact an odd one, as the solution is quite hidden: It's not back in the Antagonists Chapter of any Core book, all Spirits there have Charms instead of Gifts <sup>1, 3, 5</sup>.

It doesn't help, that page 100 of the book of Wyrm isn't a useful note on itself: there have been [3 different printings within the core game line (1st, 2nd, and W20) and a Mind's Eye Theater variant](https://rpggeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=rpgunified&q=book%20of%20wyrm), each of wich has different page numbers for different things.

In my [1998 2nd Edition](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/47551/book-wyrm-2nd-edition) printing, page 100 is within the "In Nomine Veris" chapter on BSD, describing the spread of them. Toxin Elementals are on page 124 and are listed as possessing the charms *Blighted Touch* and *Flood* <sup>2</sup>. The latter of these is described in the respective core book under general spirit charms <sup>3</sup> the former under the Bane charms <sup>4</sup>.

So you most likely have a [1994 1st Edition](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/48192/book-wyrm-1st-edition). In that, the page reference matches up. Back then, things were at times a little wonkier. In fact, the 1st Edition Core book isn't much better with describing spirit powers: most of the Charms here are half-sentence descriptions of what they should be able to do <sup>5</sup>. Though the Balefire explicitly uses the Balefire Gift <sup>6</sup>. I am thus led to believe, that in the 1st Edition Book of Wyrm, it is meant that these two charms on the Toxin Elemental are meant to emulate the same rules text as the Gift of the same names, but their note "as the XY Gift" was forgotten.

---

1. Werewolf: the Apocalypse, revised Edition (2000), pp. 282.
2. W:tA: Book of Wyrm, 2nd Edition (1998), p.124.
3. Werewolf: the Apocalypse, 2nd Editon (1994), p. 182.
4. Werewolf: the Apocalypse, 2nd Editon (1994), p. 183.
5. Werewolf: the Apocalypse, 1st Editon (1991), pp. 156.
6. W:tA: Book of Wyrm, 1st Edition (1994), p.99.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. You are correct that I have the 1994 version. Have you seen any other instances where a spirit's "powers" are gifts?

Comment: @indigochild Only in that 1994 edition: Balefires, on the page prior, with specific note that it *is* the gift meant.